# imposed to or imposed on

Tags: word-usage

Is the following sentence correct? I feel **to** is not the right preposition to use in this context. Am I correct

> The same punishment shall be **imposed to** anyone who directly or indirectly finances, contributes, or collects economic funds or resources of any nature, with knowledge that such funds or resources will be used, in whole or in part, as support....

Can I rephrase the sentence to

> The same punishment shall be **imposed on** anyone who directly or indirectly finances, contributes, or collects economic funds or resources of any nature, with knowledge that such funds or resources will be used, in whole or in part, as support....

Does the meaning of the sentence change in this scenario?

Comment: Please add the source if there is any, I am sure that impose on/upon is correct. I have no Idea about impose to

Comment: "Imposed on" is correct in American English.

Comment: What about in British English?

Comment: Why "close (2)"? any reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source seems to be [this](https://books.google.ru/books?id=81Mt9UaGaR0C&pg=PA363&lpg=PA363&dq=The+same+punishment+shall+be+imposed+to+anyone+who+directly+or+indirectly+finances,+contributes,+or+collects+economic+funds+or+resources+of+any+nature,+with+knowledge+that+such+funds+or+resources+will+be+used,+in+whole+or+in+part,+as+support....&source=bl&ots=kPDESBJcYp&sig=4BM5fNd3-6ggm9zHzQRQ51eECKg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6tf2s7cfNAhUD6CwKHZLcDPIQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q&f=false), and there's an alternative use of the preposition there:

> Article 141. A penalty of one to nine years of prison and a fine of up
>   to ten thousand pesos will be imposed on those who conspire to commit
>   one or several of the crimes of this title and plot the means to carry
>   out such conspiracy.

As soon as the only prepositions [collocating](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=impose) with the verb *impose* are *on/upon*, I'm wondering why you think it couldn't be incorrectly used with the preposition *to* in the original document, which seems to be a translation from Spanish.

Maybe in the context of the law enforcement documents, there are some special rules for the use of collocations but not to my knowledge and I seriously doubt that there are such.

Answer (score 0):

Check these contexts:
"impose fines to avoid future problems"
"fines will be imposed on those who cause problems"